# Проблема с запросом ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Проблема с запросом ajax. Пишет что ошибка, почему это происходит?

```
(function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // проверяем вернулись запрошенные данные
        if(request.readyState === 4) {
            // проверяем успешен ли запрос
            if(request.status === 200) {
                console.log('Успех');
                console.log(request.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log('Ошибка');
            }
        }
    }
    request.open('Get', 'http://...');
    request.send();
})();
```

Comment: Никогда. Слышите? НИКОГДА! Не говорите никому, что за ошибки Вы получаете. Так всем будет гораздо интереснее Вам помогать. `console.log(request.responseText);` - ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно все работать, вот ваш же код с моей ссылкой на `json`-файл:

```js
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smelukov/citiesTest/master/cities.json';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // проверяем вернулись запрошенные данные
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    // проверяем успешен ли запрос
    if (request.status === 200) {
      console.log('Успех');
      console.log(request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('Ошибка');
    }
  }
}
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send();
```

Скорее всего у вас либо не верная ссылка, либо сервер не отвечает.

---

А вообще бы рекомендовал использовать `promise`:

```js
function loadTowns() {
  var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smelukov/citiesTest/master/cities.json';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        var error = new Error(this.statusText);
        error.code = this.status;
        reject(error);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error("Network Error"));
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}

loadTowns()
  .then(resolve => {
    console.log(resolve);
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Рекомендовал бы потому, что вы делаете асинхронный запрос, и если у вас достаточно большой файл для загрузки, это может ощутимо сказаться на скорости загрузки страницы.

Comment: К сожалению мне пишет `Refused to connect to 'http://...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'. Я делаю скрипт в Tampermonkey. Почему он запрещает?

Comment: Попробуй: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">` в `header`